# What C source will compile to a call *get_func@GOTPCREL(%rip) and a cmp against another pointer from the GOT?

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, dynamic-linking

I want to generate following instructions.  What C source will compile to this asm?

```
call    *get_func@GOTPCREL(%rip)
cmpq    func@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rax
```

Comment: I cleaned up the question a lot; I *think* this is what you were asking.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a call to `get_func()` compiled with `-fno-plt`, then comparing the return value against the address of another function.

I used `void*` instead of declaring a function that returns a function pointer, because that's easier.  This is a [c](/questions/tagged/c) question so everything can convert to / from `void*` without casts.

```
void func();
void *get_func(void);  // returns a function pointer
int foo(void) {
  return func == get_func();
}
```

[source + asm on Godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,source:'void+func()%3B%0Avoid+*get_func(void)%3B++//+returns+a+function+pointer%0Aint+foo(void)+%7B%0A++return+func+%3D%3D+get_func()%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:47.28568638937708,l:'4',m:64.95049504950495,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:2,editor:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%232+with+x86-64+clang+5.0.0',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:35.04950495049505,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:32.47647862129863,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g72,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',trim:'1'),libs:!(),options:'-xc+-O3+-Wall++-fno-plt',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+7.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)',t:'0')),header:(),k:36.22130955100127,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g72,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',trim:'1'),libs:!(),options:'-xc+-O3+-Wall+-Dwithout_PIC_position_dependent_executable',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+7.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%233)',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:36.22130955100127,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang500,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',trim:'1'),libs:!(),options:'-xc+-Oz+-Wall+-fPIC',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+5.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)',t:'0')),header:(),k:31.3022118277001,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

```
    # gcc7.2 -O3 -fno-plt
    subq    $8, %rsp
    # your lines verbatim in the compiler output
    call    *get_func@GOTPCREL(%rip)
    cmpq    func@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rax

    sete    %al
    addq    $8, %rsp
    movzbl  %al, %eax
    ret
```

With or without a PLT, the function address will come from the GOT, but with the traditional `-fplt` (which is still the default), the `call` instruction will be a `rel32` call to the PLT in this executable or shared object.

e.g. with just `-fPIC`:

```
    call    get_func@PLT
    cmpq    func@GOTPCREL(%rip), %rax
```

or without either (for just a position-dependent executable, so the address of `func` is a link-time constant):

```
    call    get_func        # converted at link-time to a PLT call if it's in a shared lib
    cmpq    $func, %rax
```

Related: [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux) Many distros make gcc enable `-pie` / `-fPIE` by default.

---

clang is smarter, and xor-zeroes `eax` before cmp, so there's no `movzbl` on the critical path.  But the call/cmp are basically the same.

clang doesn't have a no-PLT option.

Comment: thanks  a lot for your explanation  but how to compile c file with -fno-plt option it is giving error that  unrecognized command line option ‘-fno-plt’

Comment: @Akshay: What compiler are you using, on what OS?  I was testing with gcc/clang targeting Linux, but OS X might be different.  As I said, clang doesn't have a `-fno-plt` option (yet), but perhaps it generates code without a PLT on some targets.

Comment: I am using gcc 4.8.5  and linux os (cent os )

Comment: @Akshay: If you want it to emit code like that without a PLT, then yes.  But why exactly do you want that?  (However, using a gcc version that old is a bad idea in general, so I'd recommend gcc 6.4 or maybe even 7.2 if you're willing to upgrade.)  I have no idea why you specifically want to reproduce that asm, or what problem you're trying to solve, but a more recent gcc is rarely a bad idea.

Comment: actually i have another compiler and I want to see what are the corresponding instructions in that compiler that is  why I need to reproduce this asm with c code so I can see the  corresponding  behavior in another compiler

Comment: @Akshay that's "housekeeping" or platform-implementation-specific piece of code, so it's sort of weird to compare it between different compilers/platforms, I don't see what kind of purpose that may have. Comparing the real "body" part of code, which is actually doing something, would make sense, but whatever the target compiler+platform is doing to emulate C abstract machine is sort of uninteresting, unless you are working on the C compiler itself or fixing some platform bug. And there's no generic C source to produce that asm, it will happen only on specific target+compiler+options.